# Convert a dgCMatrix to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, dplyr

I would like to convert the following sparse matrix `dgCMatrix` into a data frame:

`744 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"`

The matrix looks as follows:

```
$group_x

744 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
      1
ABCZ  4
ACDY  .        
KDEF  .        
AKDA  .        
LOLP  .        
RABQ  .        
OPWQ  .        
....
LDLX 10.0
```

I tried the usual `as.data.frame(as.matrix(group_x))` but I get the following:

```r
A data.frame: 1 x 1
V1
<named list>
group_x <S4 class ‘dgCMatrix’ [package “Matrix”] with 6 slots>
```

The sought output is a 744x2 data frame that looks as follows:

```r
Group Value
ABCZ  4
ACDY  0        
KDEF  0        
AKDA  0        
LOLP  0        
RABQ  0        
OPWQ  0        
....
LDLX 10.0
```

Comment: How do you generated the dgCMatrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have your matrix inside a list.

```r
library(Matrix)
m <- matrix(c(1,4,rep(0,100),10), ncol = 1)
group_x <- as(m, "Matrix")
```

`as.data.frame(as.matrix(..))` works fine:

```r
str(as.data.frame(as.matrix(group_x)))
## 'data.frame':    103 obs. of  1 variable:
##  $ V1: num  1 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

but:

```r
gx <- list(group_x)
as.data.frame(as.matrix(gx))
##                                                       V1
## 1 <S4 class ‘dgCMatrix’ [package “Matrix”] with 6 slots>
```

So if what you have is `gx`, then

```r
data.frame(Group = rownames(gx[[1]]), Value = gx[[1]][,1])
```

should work.